# Setup Google Analytics to trigger new session with dimension change

Tags: android, ios, session, google-analytics

I've been getting weird results when running some custom segments over my app data in Google Anayltics. I have custom segments setup for specific app versions. e.g. Custom Segment -> Conditions -> App Version - exactly matches - 1.1.0

Using a secondary dimension of App Version on tables running against this segment, you would expect all the values to simply be 1.1.0. However my data also contains some values for 1.0.8 (my last build version before the minor update).

Reading the [Google SDK docs on sessions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sessions) (for iOS, but basically the same for Android) it states hits within 30 minutes are grouped into the same session. I'm guessing what is happening is people are opening the app, updating, and opening the new version all within 30 minutes, resulting in a single session with 2 different version numbers.

1. Is my guess about what is happening correct?
2. If so, is there a way to setup something within GA (server side) to trigger a new session when a specific dimension changes?
3. Or is it expected that you manually trigger a new session during every app launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) yes.

2) if by "server-side" you mean "within the GA interface", then no.

3) Yes. dimensions are arbitrary data to give insight about visitors. They aren't meant to act as switches or the like.  So you are expected to trigger a new session, because that's what it's there for.

And anyways, you should be triggering a new session start on each app open anyways.  It's the equivalent of if a visitor were to go to a website, leave and then come back.  In the web analytics world, reporters expect this to count as a new visit. Unfortunately, the way GA works, it doesn't count, because of that 30m timeout.  And GA didn't offer a solution to this until [Universal Analytics version](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#sessionControl) (the one with `ga()` calls. There is no equivalent with `_gaq.()` calls, which is what most people still use :( ).

Comment: Thanks, thought so, just wanted to get confirmation. While it makes sense that GA makes no assumptions on their server side processing, I thought maybe their mobile SDKs would have more intelligence in them (such as new session on new app launches).

Comment: PS. I think you made a typo. 'you should be triggering a new session start on each API open anyways' is supposed to be 'app', not 'API', correct?

Comment: yeah sorry, meant app

Comment: @Tyson tbh, from a reporting perspective, it would actually upset me if i got spikes in visit(or)s just because a new app version was pushed.  That would be misleading numbers IMO.